# How to generate WKT in the INSERT command for PostgreSQL with ogr2ogr

Tags: postgresql, ogr2ogr

My problem is that I have some Mapinfo files where the polygon has holes with the extent of zero, like POLYGON((35 10, 45 45, 15 40, 10 20, 35 10),
(20 30, 35 35, 20 30)). That is legal in Mapinfo and ogr2ogr can also handle it, but when ogr2ogr makes an insert in the PostgreSQL table, PostgreSQL generates the error:

- INSERT command for new feature failed. ERROR: geometry requires more points

and that is because the hole in the polygon needs one point more to have an extent. How can I solve this?

Info: I receive the Mapinfo files from another system, which i cannot influnce, so I need a solution that can handler the polygon as specified above.